# How to start NodeJS Server when opening website?

Tags: node.js, web, server

my question is: How can i start my `server` from my website server-folder when its online? I haven't uploaded my server folder so far.

currently, my folder structure is:

```
public
  - index.html
  - index.css
  - index.js

server
  - server.js
```

When i open my website, i also want my server to run, so i can make requests to it.

Comment: you are going to need to host your application on a server. Do you have it hosted somewhere right now, or just locally and stored in `github`? If you don't, i would recommend `heroku`.

Comment: @Gianluca hey, thank you for your message. It's already deployed via Netlify. the website is www.thatguybryan.com, but it's still static / not using a server.

Comment: np! and yes, so since you are have a `node.js` backend, you are going to need to host the application on a server that hosts node.js backend code. It cannot be a static site. My suggestion is `heroku`, very simple to use.